# Docker cant create Jar file

Tags: docker, kotlin, gradle

Trying to docker my web app with gradle.
But gradle dosnt create a lib directory with Jar

I checked my folders by  `RUN ls -al /home/gradle/src/build/` but folder is empty

[image]

My docker file is:

```
FROM gradle:7.1.1-jdk11 AS build

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle addCredentials --key nexusLogin --value "62" && \
    gradle addCredentials --key nexusPassword --value "!" && \
    gradle build --no-daemon

RUN ls -al /home/gradle/src/build/

FROM openjdk:11.0.11-9-slim

RUN mkdir /app

COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar /app/target-discovery.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/target-discovery.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle by default builds the jar file in

```
lib/build/libs
```

not in

```
src/build
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle build files in this directory:
`lib/build/libs`